# Ubuntu 12.10 & Canon LBP7750

Tags: 12.10, printing, canon

I can't get a network printer running...

Ubuntu 12.10, 64 bit
Cups version: 1.6.1
Printer: Canon LBP7750

I already installed the driver from canon. (using .deb package). But if I print, I just get some characters... And also message: "If you can read this, you are using wrong driver for your printer".

I installed cups-driver and UFR II driver (both 64 bit), then restarted cups and finally registered printer (ppd) at at printer spooler.

Any hints?

EDIT:
Works with driver for LBP5360 (but not duplex, but do not know if 5360 even has duplex)

Answer (score 1):

Try with installing Cannon LBP driver in Official Ubuntu Repository. It is much trusted.

```
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-cjet cjet
```

Comment: Let us know if it works.